# Unzip and save bz2 file in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bzip2

I need to decompress a gzip file that contains other files and directories, and save these files separately, it is possible to do this in iOS?

My compressed file has the following structure

```
file.tar.bz2 
   - db_update.sql 
   - Tmp / 
     - image.png 
     - image2.png
```

I found documentation that shows how to do that, but only for when the archive is a single file.

Need to save it in the **same archive's structure**, is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do here.

1. Serialized the directory structure using something like `tar`. For tar, use [`libarchive`](https://code.google.com/p/libarchive/).
2. Switch from using `gzip` to `zip`. `zip` (also called PK zip) can compress a directory structure instead of just a single file. For `zip` look into [`minizip`](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html).

As [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789332/unzip-and-save-bz2-file-in-objective-c/21789399#comment32968279_21789399) stated in a comment, you already have a `tar`ed file. If you want to go with a .tar.gz format (sometimes given as .tgz), then you only need to decompress the `bzip2` part of `file.tar.bz2`, which will leave you with a `file.tar`. At that point you can recompress with gzip.

Comment: Looks like he has a .tar.bz2 file already, he just doesn't know the difference.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I should have paid more attention.